# Not getting the desired output (using POSTMAN)

Tags: postman

I am trying to get all the information related to a product using this endpoint:

> {{URL_API}}/products/96PHLFR71B/03

The problem is that POSTMAN **cannot find** the product because of the '/' within the SKU

Take a look at this:

[image]

The product 96PHLFR71B/03 **exists** but POSTMAN cannot find it because it tries to find something after the '/'

How can i fix it?